# Sculpt looks pixilated

Tags: shaders, sculpting, topology, dynamic-topology, sculpt

[image]

This is a leaf to a Chinese money plant that I've been working on. I went into sculpt mode to add the veins. But, when I try to sculpt any detail, it comes out looking a bit... Chunky. Like it's pixalated or something. When I watch tutorials of other folks using Blender, the sculpts look perfect and crisp. From what I can tell, they are not doing anything different than from what I'm doing. Also, this is in smooth shading, and I can see topology of the object clearly, as if it were in flat shading. I tried to pick a nice matcap so that you all can see the odd "chunky" effect on the veins. And again, thank you all in advance!

Comment: Your model does not have enough vertices for that level of detail. Either increase the subdivision or use dynamic topology.

Comment: try setting your shading to smooth. in the left[in the transform tab[ edit[ smooth shading

Comment: Double check it really is in smooth shading - blender can set this at the per-face level in edit mode, so assign the object smooth shading again from object mode to be certain it affects all of the faces.

Comment: I double checked the smooth shading, and I did use dynamic topology. Sorry it took me forever to respond, I work at a summer camp.